NoneType is not subscriptable. xcom_pull from extract_user is not getting the results in airflow
I am learning  airflow. I have just developed a DAG file where tasks are
CREATE_TABLE= create a user table in post_gres db,
IS_API_AVAILABLE= check API of a web site,
extract_user= Get the data in json format ,
process_user= Process the data into a file mapped the table features,
Store_user= using a webhook it call copy_expert method and  store the data from file

Problem: in airflow task testing create_table, is_api_available, extract_user are working  but process_user is giving None Type is not subscribable error. This is the exception message

File "/opt/***/dags/user_processing.py", line 33, in _process_user
raise ValueError("No data was pulled from Xcom for task 'extract_user'") ValueError: No data was pulled from Xcom for task
'extract_user'

The code
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime

# A provider for interact and response the request from Postgress 
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator
#interacting with database for some execution those are not hard to access by operator. we will use Hook

from airflow.providers.postgres.hooks.postgres import PostgresHook

#A provide for Http response sensor
from airflow.providers.http.sensors.http import HttpSensor
#operator will be used for extracting data from http  api , is_api_available is already define as task
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator
# Python operator for airflow
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

#Normalizing raw json
from pandas import json_normalize

import json
import logging


# TI parameter is  task instance parameter
# this will pull the data that task is extracted .it is yet to be revealed

def _process_user(ti):
    user=ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='extract_user')
    #log the pull data for debugging
    logging.info(f"Data pulled from XCom:{user}")
    if user is None:
        raise ValueError("No data was pulled from Xcom for task 'extract_user'")
    
    # #check if expected key exist in the data
    # if 'results' not in user or not user['results']:
    #     raise ValueError("The key 'results' is missing  or empty in the XCom Data.")
    
    user=user['results'][0]
    processed_user=json_normalize({'firstname':user['name']['first'],
    'lastname':user['name']['last'],'country':user['location']['country'],
    'username':user['login']['username'],'password':user['login']['password'],
    'email':user['email']}
    )
    
    print(processed_user.head(5))
    #saving normalized file into csv file 
    filepath='/tmp/check_user.csv'
    logging.info(f"Type of processed_user:{type(processed_user)}")
    processed_user.to_csv(filepath,index=None,header=False)

def _store_user():
    #connect with postgress through postgress id
    hook=PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='postgres')
    #copy expert method will copy from csv file to db table 'users'
    hook.copy_expert(
        sql="COPY users FROM stdin WITH DELIMITER as ','",
        filename='/tmp/check_user.csv'
    )

# You have to define dag object now 
# the first parameter will be your DAG_ID  which is the file name  in this case "user_processing" this ithe unique
#apply start date where the DAG has been schedulted

#setting schedule it would be cron configuration
#catchup parameter will be forcefully set at FALSE



with DAG('user_processing',start_date=datetime(2024,1,1),schedule_interval='@daily',catchup=False)as dag:
    # our task is to create a table in postgress db
    #since task_id is unique so it is better practice name the variable and task_id same for clear visiblity
    
    create_table=PostgresOperator(
        task_id='create_table',
        postgres_conn_id='postgres', # this is the connection id for interacting postgres
        sql="""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
            firstname TEXT NOT NULL,
            lastname TEXT NOT NULL,
            country TEXT NOT NULL,
            username TEXT NOT NULL,
            password TEXT NOT NULL,
            email TEXT NOT NULL
        ) """
    )
    
    is_api_available=HttpSensor(
        task_id='is_api_available',
        http_conn_id='user_api',
        endpoint='api/'
    )
    
    extract_user=SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='extract_user',
        http_conn_id='user_api',
        endpoint='api/',
        #request  to API use GET for data
        method='GET',
        #response filter for transforming the data into json format
        response_filter=lambda response:json.loads(response.text),
        #taking the log from response
        log_response=True
    )
    
    process_user=PythonOperator(
        task_id='process_user',
        python_callable=_process_user #this is a function which will be exeuted for data processing from API
        
    )
    store_user=PythonOperator(
        task_id='store_user',
        python_callable=_store_user
    )
    
    
    #creating  dependancies with extract user and process user
    # the reason the xcom will be generated from extract_user in our case and then process_user .
    # so process user is dependent on extract user
    
    extract_user >> process_user
    
    
    #create_table>>is_api_available>>extract_user>>process_user

What i have checked

I checked extract_user x_com tab in apache airflow and got the entries
return_value    {'results': [{'gender': 'male', 'name': {'title': 'Mr', 'first': 'پرهام', 'last': 'سالاری'}, 'location': {'street': {'number': 1407, 'name': 'شهید سرتیپ نامجو'}, 'city': 'قائم\u200cشهر', 'state': 'چهارمحال و بختیاری', 'country': 'Iran', 'postcode': 57546, 'coordinates': {'latitude': '15.1752', 'longitude': '-112.0645'}, 'timezone': {'offset': '+7:00', 'description': 'Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta'}}, 'email': 'prhm.slry@example.com', 'login': {'uuid': 'f4d27ac8-ebc9-47c7-87a5-b415f2c75755', 'username': 'redfrog758', 'password': 'intrepid', 'salt': '6UXLDVCF', 'md5': '7618ccf14f13e2614e2dcf6d1c8e400b', 'sha1': 'c252f007ab43c8c7f3df1276309faf574416fdd0', 'sha256': '8177301792b569f62500449a5002c62ff111e79001552ee82280a1b887f68ad0'}, 'dob': {'date': '1960-07-30T11:57:08.378Z', 'age': 64}, 'registered': {'date': '2004-09-08T05:34:44.227Z', 'age': 19}, 'phone': '091-74343350', 'cell': '0907-166-2827', 'id': {'name': '', 'value': None}, 'picture': {'large': 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/32.jpg', 'medium': 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/32.jpg', 'thumbnail': 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/32.jpg'}, 'nat': 'IR'}], 'info': {'seed': '1c7367efad63102a', 'results': 1, 'page': 1, 'version': '1.4'}}

I have also checked the process_user  x_com tab but didn't find any entries there
also checked the log tab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 175, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 192, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/user_processing.py", line 39, in _process_user
    processed_user.to_csv('/tmp/processed_user.csv',index=None,header=False)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'to_csv'



my working version airflow version is 2.5.1
